# Given an XSD is it possible to list a hierarchy of elements and their attributes?

Tags: xsd, code-completion

Lets pretend I have an XSD document and I want to produce a list of all elements along with their attributes and the children of the elements.  I could also approach this by asking if you are to implement code completion based on an xsd document, and you want to list the children of the element and an elements attributes, how would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since XSD is valid XML document it just a matter of selecting XML parsing library of your choice. For example XLinq (.NET FW 3+) will do the job.

You can just walk through **complexType**, **sequence** and other elements to find out a list of possible values.